# Quick way to validate and convert Audio Files with Python?

Tags: python, django, audio

For a website i am developing in django i need users to be able to upload .wav or .aif files. I, of course, have to make sure these files really are what they pretend to be - audiofiles. The files then are provided on the webpage, where i need them to be either .ogg or .mp3

While searching for a solution i stumbled across some fearsome possibilities, like using ctypes to handle external libraries. I also found, of course, PyMedia, which i cannot use because i develop on MacOSX. And the python audio tools provide a lot of functionality i do not need.

So far i can see a few possibilities that would satisfy me and are within reach of my programming capabilities:

**1** Get PyMedia to run on MacOSX
**2** Find a way to use some modules of the python audio tools without the need to use libcdio
**3** use python subprocess to run the command line tools of the converters

As i have used none of those tools yet, i can't tell which would possibly be the quickest way to solve my problem. If you Python-Audio-Gurus are out there, could you please share some thoughts? Or maybe you even have a fantastic 1-step-to-happiness solution?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for validation? I'm trying to do the exact same thing ("make sure these files are really what they pretend to be - audiofiles") but so far have had no luck. If you've found an answer, sharing would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Hey Matt. I used the way Kekoa proposed. Using sox via subprocess figured to be a pretty good way to do it. I am able to catch all the errors, do validations and conversions as i need them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not strictly a pythonic answer, but perhaps take a look at [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) which is a simple command line audio file converter.  It can do resampling of audio files for you as well.

Check out the [command line options](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) of [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) for details.  This will of course involve calling the external program using the `subprocess` module(or other method).

Comment: Sound like a good solution to me. I would appreciate if you could help me further with two things: **1 (important and the reason why i didn't accept your answer yet)** How would i validate uploaded files with sox? **2 (not so important)** allthough lame-398 is installed, sox refuses to convert to mp3. If you are working with sox and have a quick answer on that, please let me know.

Comment: ok, if you could just answer **1** of my comment that would be great. For **2** i'm goint to use the lame commandline tool directly